# Приведение DataFrame в порядок (на примере прайса)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

У меня есть вымышленная задача, с каждым этапом которой сталкивается любой новичок.
Русское сообщество развивается, но схожая типовая задачка в вопросы не ставится. 
Можно найти урывки решения, но в более сложных задачах с большим количеством кода, где можно потеряться в взаимосвязях функций.

Представьте, что у задающего вопрос есть `Numpy`, `Pandas`, `re` и файл такого содержания:

[image: Исходник]

Типовой прайс плохого поставщика, который "случайно" наполнил файл ошибками.

Файл нужно скорректировать, поправив следующее:

1. Убрать пустые строки
2. Из наименования убрать артикул (в скобках | без скобок)
3. Убрать "денежные" признаки в значениях
4. Установить NaN для "Тариф" и "МРЦ" - если значение "Закупочная" больше
5. Установить "МРЦ" равным значению закупочной, если в "МРЦ" значения 0 или текст.

Вот так должно выглядеть решение:
[image: Решение задачи]

Так как широкому кругу нужны отдельные решения - применять последовательность действий, избегая функций и типовых "for". Чистый функционал Pandas, будто последовательность действий - новые строки в jupyter.

[Файл-пример](https://yadi.sk/i/nOR7rsru3Z2XxZ)

Сможете ? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# 1
df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)

# 2
df.loc[:, 'Наименование'] = [re.sub('\s*\(\s*\)', '', n.replace(a, '')).strip()
                             for a, n in zip(df['Артикул'], df['Наименование'])]

# 3
df.loc[:, 'Закупочная'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Закупочная']
                                         .astype(str)
                                         .str.replace('[^\d\.]+', ''), 
                                        errors='coerce')

# 4
df['МРЦ'] = pd.to_numeric(df['МРЦ'], errors='coerce')
df.loc[df['Закупочная'] > df['МРЦ'], 'Тариф'] = np.nan

# 5
df.loc[df['МРЦ'].isna() | df['МРЦ'].eq(0), 'МРЦ'] = df['Закупочная']
```

---

Результат:

```
In [289]: df
Out[289]:
   Артикул Наименование   Тариф     МРЦ  Закупочная
0    AB1-1       Товар1   100.0    80.0        50.0
1      AA2       Товар2   150.0   130.0       100.0
2      AA3       Товар3   200.0   180.0       150.0
3      AA4       Товар4     NaN   150.0       180.0
4      AA5       Товар5   300.0   250.0       200.0
5      AA6       Товар6     NaN   340.0      2500.0
6      AA7       Товар7   500.0   400.0       300.0
7      AA8       Товар8  1000.0   800.0       600.0
8      AA9       Товар9     NaN  1600.0      2500.0
9     AA10      Товар10  2500.0  1700.0      1700.0
10    AA11      Товар11  4000.0  3300.0      3000.0
11    AA12      Товар12     NaN  6000.0      6000.0
12    AA13      Товар13  8001.0  6701.0      6001.0
13    AA14      Товар14  8002.0  6702.0      6002.0
14    AA15      Товар15  8003.0  6703.0      6003.0
15    AA16      Товар16  8004.0  6004.0      6004.0
16    AA17      Товар17  8005.0  6705.0      6005.0
17    AA18      Товар18  8006.0  6006.0      6006.0
18    AA19      Товар19  8007.0  6707.0      6007.0
20    AA20      Товар20  8008.0  6708.0      6008.0
```

Comment: Удивительный человек, умения которого на многих хватает :-). Крут!
Без скобок в первой строке есть универсальное решение по вхождению исключить артикул?

Comment: @APmansib, вы можете описать правило по которому можно отличить артикул от наименования?

Comment: Правило простое  - точное вхождение значения из столбца артикул в состав наименования.

Comment: Два столбца - артикул и наименование
Данные в ячейках :
ABC  ТоварABC
ABC  ABCТовар
ABC  ТоABCвар
Суть в исключении полного содержимого ячейки в столбце "Артикул" из наименования независимо от местонахождения его в ячейке столбца "Наименование"

Comment: @APmansib, скорее всего это придется циклом делать - не люблю использовать циклы в Pandas... ;-)

Comment: Не Уважаемый... Вы великий и непобедимый - я в Вас верю.
Должен быть обезцикленный вариант или вариант с циклом в решении. :-)

Comment: Вижу, что решения дополнены, @MaxU спасибо